How to keep ag grid filter after selecting all filtered?
I have an ag grid table that I am filtering, and upon a button click it is set to select all the rows that are currently filtered using selectAllFiltered(), and after clicking the button the filtered rows are selected but the filter is reset. How do I prevent the filter form resetting?
js = JsCode("""
 function(event) {
    const api = event.api; 
     window.addEventListener('clear.rows', (e) => {
        api.deselectAll();
     });
     window.addEventListener('select.rows', (e) => {
        api.selectAllFiltered();

     });    
 }
 """)

if st.sidebar.button('Select All Filtered Rows'):
    selectJs = '''<script>
     ((e) => {
        const iframe = window.parent.document.querySelectorAll('[title="st_aggrid.agGrid"]')[0] || null;
        if(!iframe) return;
        iframe.contentWindow.dispatchEvent( new Event('select.rows'));
     })()
    </script>
    '''
    components.html(selectJs)

